# Django/Python control: "if form.is_valid ():" is equal to false if the form has an input type "button"

Tags: javascript, html, django, json, python-2.7

I don't understand why if I have in my html page in a form: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" id="execute"` value="Esegui">`

then the form is valid otherwise if I put a 
    `<input class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button" id="execute"` value="Esegui"> 
the form is invalid.
The problem is that if I put as "input type" the submit then fails to load JSON's code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a # single_image").fancybox();
    $("# execute").click(function () {
        var execute = true
        $("# execute").attr("value", "Run ...");
        $("# single_image.") attr("href", "");
        $("# image").attr("src", "");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ cloud / carica_immagine"
            date: {
                execute: execute
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $("# execute").attr("value", "Run");
            $("# single_image.") attr("href", "graphs /" + msg["user_id"] + "/" + msg["graph"] + ."png");
            $("# image").attr("src", "graphs /" + msg["user_id"] + "/" + msg["graph"] + ."png");
            $("# single_image.") trigger("click");
        });
    });
})
</ script>.
```

This is my view that is called by html page:

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            print newdoc.docfile
            newdoc.save() 
            ...
            ...
            return render_to_response('processa_immagine.html', {'documents':documents, 'form': form, 'user_id':request.session['user_id'],'graph':graph}, RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form        

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response('processa_immagine.html', {'documents':documents, 'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

This is my forms:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Seleziona un file',help_text='massimo 42 megabytes',
    )
```

This is my models:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

my page html with form is:

```
<form method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }} </p>
  <p>{{ form.docfile }}</p>             
  <input class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button" id="execute" value="Esegui"><br/> 
</form>
```

I hope that someone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *can* indent JavaScript code too.

Comment: with `<input type=button` you are not actually submitting the form. You need to explicitly call `.submit()`. Hence the error

Comment: How can I do? Should I put this in the form:
<input class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="button" onclick="submitform()" id="execute" value="Esegui"> <br/>
and under the function js:
<script type="text/javascript">
submitForm function () {
document.myform.submit ();
}
</ script>

Answer (score 0):

This code is very confused. You have defined an Ajax function on your button triggered on the click event. So, when you click the button, that function is triggered, and it tries to submit the form. However, it cannot do so in a way that will make the form valid: the only field in the form is a required FileField, which cannot be submitted via a standard Ajax POST - and even if it could, your Ajax function makes no attempt to actually include it.

The reason why the `input` version appears to work is that the Javascript does not prevent the default submit action, so the process is this: the Ajax is run, but even before it has a chance to receive a response, the entire page is submitted, and refreshes with the result of the (valid) form submission.

Comment: In fact, I would like understand how I could do submit the form and at the same time make a call using the JSON through the button "execute".

Comment: Well you can't do that because you're trying to submit a file, as I stated.

Comment: I am interested in uploading an image, make the change via the view and then display it.
Is it possible that there is a way?

Comment: So what? no one can help me?
I need to know if there is a way that allows me to perform the submit the form and at the same time to open an image via Javascript.

Comment: No-one can help you because no-one has the slightest idea what you are trying to do. What do you mean, open an image "at the same time" as submitting the form? Why can't you submit the form then have the image on the page that comes back?

Comment: I have a form that allows me to upload images.
I created a method in "view.py" that modify the loaded image and I would like to display it on the same page with a window that opens up the modified image.
So if I understand correctly, I should leave it in the form "submit" and switch the image displayed by the view?
How could I do?

Comment: no one can answer me?
I've try to apply in my view:
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"graph": graph, "user_id": user_id}), 'application/json')

Comment: no one can answer me?
I've try to apply in my view:
'return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"graph": graph, "user_id": user_id}), 'application/json')'

Where graph and user_id; are strings that contain the name of the path of the image, that I should open with:
'$("#single_image").attr("href","graphs/"+msg["user_id"]+"/"+msg["graph"]+".png");
  $("#image").attr("src","graphs/"+msg["user_id"]+"/"+msg["graph"]+".png");'